# Django templates fetch wrong static file url on sub-route

Tags: python, html, django

Simple problem, not sure how else to explain it other than pasting my code here.... The images are loading on the index view, not the category_photos view.

Here are the HTTP responses that will illustrate this perfectly:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16912
"GET /static/media/uploads/CF-10.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/media/uploads/CF-08.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/media/uploads/CF-09.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /group/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16194
"GET /group/2/static/media/uploads/CF-09.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 13515
"GET /group/2/static/media/uploads/CF-08.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 13515
"GET /group/2/static/media/uploads/CF-10.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 13515
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from portfolio import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'portfolio.views.index', name='index'),

    url(r'group/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        'portfolio.views.category_photos',
        name="category_photos"),
)
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    context = {'groups': groups}
    return render(request, 'portfolio/index.html', context)

def category_photos(request, pk):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    selected = Group.objects.filter(id=pk)[0]

    return render(request, 'portfolio/individual-group.html', {'groups': groups, 'selected': selected})
```

## Relevant templates:

**index.html (THIS ONE WORKS)**

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <h2 class="clearfix:before" id="{{group.abbv}}">{{group.title}}</h1>
    <div id="gallery-{{group.id}}" class="gallery container">

        {% for photo in group.photos.all %}
        <div class="box">
            <a href="/{{ photo.image.url }}" title="{{ photo.category_image }}">
                <img src="/{{photo.image.url}}" alt="{{photo.category_image}}">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**individual-group.html (>>>>THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK<<<<)**

```
{% for photo in selected.photos.all %}
<div class="box">
    <a href="/{{photo.image.url }}" title="{{ photo.category_image }}">
        <img src="/{{photo.image.url}}" alt="{{photo.category_image}}">
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

## Settings.py

**only including the media/static stuff as i'm pretty sure thats what th eproblem is**

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/media')
MEDIA_URL = 'static/media/uploads/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: why do you have a `./` ? Ideally, you shoul be doing `{{STATIC_URL}}{{{{photo.image.url}}}}` `./` is looking for the path relative to the current working directory, whereas `/` is looking from the project root, which is 2 directories above the current directory

Comment: oh, i was experimenting, that may not be in there anymore. let me look again.

Comment: ok, re-confirmed there is a leading slash - which i agree doesn't seem ideal and leads me to believe something is still funky w/ my config.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i'm open to other answers that may explain this, but this fixed it - plz let me know if this is stupid in any way.

## urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
```

...yes... hours... HOURS to figure this out.  I'm gonna go cry myself to sleep.